# How Do Websites Detect Bot-Like Cursor Movement

Tags: javascript, html, mouse-cursor

How the cursor moves on a website can tell a big story. It could be used to determine if someone is a human or not.

Is the `mousemove` event the only way to track cursor movement?

Something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   $(document).mousemove(function(e){
      $('#status').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
   }); 
})
```

Then I could have some algorithm to detect if the mouse is actually being moved. That's it's not moving in a 100% straight line all the time. Is this all I've got to work with?

Is this how Websites like Facebook would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your idea about detecting mouse movements! It's also the first post I've seen (with the selenium tag) that talks detecting selenium instead of just getting around detection.

I think the reality of bot detection is much less exciting.

[Standing on the shoulders of giants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver) - a clever method of detection is done by identifying global javascript variables used by selenium/chromedriver.

That post also talks about how to modify your chromedriver with a hex-editor to update your variable name in order to avoid detection - with lots of mixed responses.

There are also [companies out there](https://www.imperva.com/products/advanced-bot-protection-management/) which sell bot-protection-systems. And even a [forrester report](https://www.imperva.com/resources/resource-library/reports/forrester-new-wave-bot-management-q1-2020-13-providers-that-matter-most-and-how-they-stack-up/) which outlines many companies in this market. There is even an [open source](https://github.com/sheharbano/BotFlex) version. You can potentially investigate some of those companies if you need bot protection ideas/approaches.